# Fastest way to find the number of unique elements in a string

Tags: ruby, string

How can I find unique elements in a string in the best way?

Sample string format is

```
myString = "34345667543"
```

o/p

```
  ['3','4','3','5'.....]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260278/remove-duplicate-numbers-and-operators-from-string

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and since it returns so many almost similar results, I did a simple benchmark to decide which is actually the best solution:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'

puts "Do the test"

Benchmark.bm(40) do |x|

  STRING_TEST = "26263636362626218118181111232112233"

  x.report("do split and uniq") do
    (1..1000000).each { STRING_TEST.split(//).uniq }
  end

  x.report("do chars to_a uniq") do
    (1..1000000).each { STRING_TEST.chars.to_a.uniq }
  end

  x.report("using Set") do
    (1..1000000).each { Set.new(STRING_TEST.split('')).to_a }
  end

end
```

and the results of this test are, not entirely surprising (0n 1.8.7p352):

```
                                              user     system      total        real
do split and uniq                        27.060000   0.000000  27.060000 ( 27.084629)
do chars to_a uniq                       14.440000   0.000000  14.440000 ( 14.452377)
using Set                                41.740000   0.000000  41.740000 ( 41.760313)
```

and on 1.9.2p180 :

```
                                              user     system      total        real
do split and uniq                        19.260000   0.000000  19.260000 ( 19.242727)
do chars to_a uniq                        8.980000   0.010000   8.990000 (  8.983891)
using Set                                28.220000   0.000000  28.220000 ( 28.186787)
```

The results for REE (1.8.7) are close to 1.9.2 :

```
                                              user     system      total        real
do split and uniq                        19.120000   0.000000  19.120000 ( 19.126034)
do chars to_a uniq                       14.740000   0.010000  14.750000 ( 14.766540)
using Set                                32.770000   0.120000  32.890000 ( 32.921878)
```

For fun, I also tried on rubinius:

```
                                              user     system      total        real
do split and uniq                        26.100000   0.000000  26.100000 ( 26.651468)
do chars to_a uniq                       25.680000   0.000000  25.680000 ( 25.780944)
using Set                                22.500000   0.000000  22.500000 ( 22.649291)
```

So while the `split('\\').uniq` wins points for readability, the `chars.to_a.uniq` is almost double as fast.

It is weird to notice that on rubinius the `Set` solution is the fastest, but no where near as fast as the `chars.to_a.uniq` on 1.9.2.

Comment: Those times are so small it could be within the margin of error. Try increasing the number of repeats from 400 to roughly 4 million.

Comment: @andrew yaa in my case its round about 2 million

Comment: @andrew: I updated the benchmark, and now I iterate 1 million times, plus I added the results for ruby 1.8.7, ree, 1.9.2 and rubinius (just for fun/educational/hobby purposes).

Comment: @nathanvda: Thanks for that. It's interesting that the results are so similar for Rubinius. Maybe they do chars by using split.

Answer (score 8):

Use this short:

```
myString.split(//).uniq
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>> "34345667543".chars.uniq
=> ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

Comment: #chars(String) returns an array. So you can omit `.to_a` resulting in a more succinct `"34345667543".chars.uniq`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the split method:

```
"12345".split("")
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. Al this does is split the string into individual characters, it doesn't find the unique characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set.new("34345667543".chars)
```

I find this reads well: create a Set (which implies unique entries) from the characters in the string.

This is missing from the benchmark above, and is the second fastest in my tests with 1.9.3-p274 (fastest is the chars.to_a.uniq). Although we're still talking microbenchmarks here, pretty unlikely to matter in an application :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the characters from a string and make a Set out of them:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'set'
irb(main):002:0> Set.new("123444454321".split(''))
=> #<Set: {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}>
```

The `.split('')` call just breaks the string into an array, character-wise.  I originally used `String#each_char`, but that was new in 1.8.7, and you didn't mention what version of Ruby you're using.